# Angular reactive forms patchValue or setValue not working - Angular 10

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular10

I am using Reactive forms, everything's good but when I am patching values, they are not updated. I tried patchValue and setValue as well, but nothing seems to work. Below is my code

```typescript
    ngOnInit(){
    this.profileForm = this.fb.group({
          'name': ['', Validators.required],
          'email': ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
          'phNumber': ['', Validators.required],
          'gender': ['', Validators.required],
          'address': ['', Validators.required],
          'city': ['', Validators.required],
          'state': ['', Validators.required],
          'pincode': ['', Validators.required]
        });
    }
```

Patching value

```typescript
    let response = res['expert'];
          this.profileForm.setValue({
            name: response.full_name,
            email: response.expert_email,
            phNumber: response.expert_mobile,
            address: response.addresss,
            city: response.city,
            state: response.state,
            pincode: response.pincode,
            gender: response.id_gender
          });
```

getting this error if I use setValue

[image]

Form values are getting set if I use patchValue,

```html
    after = {"name":"Test Name","email":"testa@gmail.com","phNumber":"9632587410","gender":1,"city":"Adilabad","state":"ANDHRA PRADESH","pincode":"2352"}

    <section class="marginBoxModelForProfile">
        <form [formGroup]="profileForm">
            <h6 class="text-left circularBold"><b>Complete Profile Details</b></h6>
            <p class="text-left circularBold grey5F font-size14">Min 300 Rs. Explanation about how they can choose and
                why they should choose the right fields. A link and details on how to join will be included in your
                booking confirmation email.</p>
            <input type="text" class="education-inputs w-100 mt-3" placeholder="Name" formControlName="name"
                [ngClass]="{'input-error': submitted && profileForm.controls.name.invalid}">
            <div class="mt-3 text-left">
                <!-- <ng-container *ngFor="let gender of genders">
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" class="mr-1" value="">
                    <span class="mr-5" formControlName="gender">
                        {{gender.gender_name}}
                    </span>
                </ng-container> -->
                <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" class="mr-1" [value]="1" (change)="onChangeGender($event)"> <span class="mr-5"
                    formControlName="gender">Male</span>
                <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" class="mr-1" [value]="2" (change)="onChangeGender($event)"> <span class="mr-5"
                    formControlName="gender">Female</span>
                <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" class="mr-1" [value]="3" (change)="onChangeGender($event)"> <span class="mr-5"
                    formControlName="gender">Other</span>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group mt-3">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text contactNumber-addon" id="basic-addon1"
                    [ngClass]="{'input-error': submitted && profileForm.controls.phNumber.invalid}">+91</span>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control contactnumber-input" placeholder="Contact Number"
                    aria-label="contactNumber" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" formControlName="phNumber"
                    [ngClass]="{'input-error': submitted && profileForm.controls.phNumber.invalid}">
            </div>
            <input type="email" class="education-inputs w-100 mt-3" placeholder="Email" formControlName="email"
                [ngClass]="{'input-error': submitted && profileForm.controls.email.invalid}">
            <input type="text" class="education-inputs w-100 mt-3" placeholder="Address" formControlName="address"
                [ngClass]="{'input-error': submitted && profileForm.controls.address.invalid}">
            <p class="font-size12 grey8E circularBook text-left mt-2">We use this detail to generate invoices and use it
                for tax purposes.</p>
            <div>
                <input type="text" class="education-inputs w-100 mt-3" placeholder="Pincode" formControlName="pincode"
                    [ngClass]="{'input-error': submitted && profileForm.controls.pincode.invalid}"
                    (change)="onChangePincode($event)">
            </div>
            <div class="text-left">
                <select name="city" id="city" class="education-inputs mt-3 mr-1 w-50" formControlName="city"
                    [ngClass]="{'input-error': submitted && profileForm.controls.city.invalid}">
                    <option value="{{city}}">{{city}}</option>
                </select>
                <select name="state" id="state" class="education-inputs mt-3 state-dropdown" formControlName="state"
                    [ngClass]="{'input-error': submitted && profileForm.controls.state.invalid}">
                    <option value="{{state}}">{{state}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </section>
```

[image]

I have used patchValue also, please help what I'm doing wrong. I am using v10.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately with the info you have shared, it is not possible to help, Are their any errors? Is the Object being set? are you calling the function to patch the values? It is not possible to tell

Comment: @OwenKelvin oh sorry for that, there are no errors, when I console.log the form the values are assigned but I cannot see the values in the UI

Comment: Can you console log `res` property?

Comment: @OwenKelvin please check, I have edited with what's required more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First Error

The problem is that the value of `response.address` is `undefined`

As you have stated you can simply use `patchValue()` to set all the defined values and that should work fine

If you need to use `setValue` for any reason then you can change the line `address: response.address,` to

```
 address: response.address ?? '',
```

We are simply checking if the value of address exists and if not set it to `''`

### Second Error

Consider below code

```
 <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" class="mr-1" value="">
    <span class="mr-5" formControlName="gender">{{gender.gender_name}}</span>
```

As the error states `span` element does not have a `ValueAccessor`
Just move the `formControlName="gender"` attribute to the `input` tag

```
 <input  formControlName="gender" type="radio" id="gender" class="mr-1" [value]="gender.value">
    <span class="mr-5">{{gender.gender_name}}</span>
```

[See this Solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pkmwp7)

### Third non-error issue

I see you using the following:

```
(change)="onChangePincode($event)"
```

You can subscribe to the form if you're using reactive forms and handle this without using `(change)` directly in the html. It has a `formControlName`, so i f you subscribe to the form changes, you can do away with this in your html.

Comment: yeah with patchValue also, it's actually not working

Comment: yeah I have edited with the error image please check but I think that's not an issue

Comment: The problem is in the html, Please share your html

Comment: when using [value]="1" for gender it's not working as expected like it's not getting checked on change and also value is displaying as "on", why is that?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this behaviour?

Comment: I have updated the solution and demo with `[value]="gender.value"`

Comment: this one is not working, I've reproduced and saved the demo please check

Comment: please share the link

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4vedct?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Gender seems to be working as expected as long as the values supplied are not the same

Answer (score 1):

patchvalue and setvalue method are used to bind the values in the controls.

if you get the response the all form control value,you will use the setValue method.otherwise you will the patchvalue method